# C++ template specialization with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, clang

I've read through a bit of the ISO (https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates) but am having trouble understanding a simple template specialization example I've come up with that only fails to work when using CMake.

Here is my example:

```
// generic.h
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void f() 
{
    cout << "Generic" << endl;
}
```

```
// specialization.cpp
#include "generic.h"

template <>
void f<int>()
{
    cout << "Specialization" << endl;
}
```

```
// main.cpp
#include "generic.h"

int main()
{
    f<char>();
    f<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(example-proj VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

add_library(example-lib
    generic.h
    specialization.cc)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main example-lib)
```

So here's were the confusion comes in:

```
# Build 1:
clang++ main.cpp specialization.cc generic.h
./a.out 

Generic
Specialization


#  Build 2:
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -j
./main

Generic
Generic
```

Clang Version: 7.1.0
CMake Version: 3.18.2

I'm either missing something about CMake or I'm dealing with undefined behavior. Either way I'm at a loss as to why building and running my executable in CMake doesn't override the generic behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to tell the compiler there is a specialization. Otherwise, it chooses the first one linker finds.

```
// generic.h
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void f() {
    cout << "Generic" << endl;
}

template<> void f<int>(); // when int, use this
```

> I've read through a bit of the ISO
>
> or I'm dealing with undefined behavior.

From https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.expl.spec-7 it's:

> If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is explicitly specialized, a declaration of that specialization shall be reachable from every use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation to take place, in every translation unit in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required.